# C# How to implement this situation on the master page?

Tags: html, css, c#-4.0, hover, navigationbar

I am doing the website which includes a master page with its navigation bar. Everything is correctly happening except one thing. I need the hover style to be the same in the sellected content page. I mean when I am browsing the home page for example the hover css style is on the `Home` icon on the navigation bar. I know its easy for you, but I am noob. I am using this html code for that:

```
<div class="nav"><ul class="navbar" >
            <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About us.aspx">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Sections.aspx">Sections</a></li>
            <li><a href="App.aspx">Appointment</a></li>
            <li><a href="Registeration.aspx">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

And implementing this css:

```
ul.navbar
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:6px 0 6px 0;
margin:0;
}

ul.navbar li
{
display:inline;
float:left;
}

.navbar a:active, .navbar a:link, .navbar a:visited
{
padding:0 14px 0 14px;
color:#32C5CF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:#cca628;
}
```

The question is should I use the server side to implement that? if yes, I am using asp.net c# language. Please help me.

ThanQ in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First give each of your list items IDs so they can be found easily.

e.g

```
<div class="nav"><ul class="navbar" >
            <li id="home_link"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about_link"><a href="About us.aspx">About us</a></li>
            <li id="sect_link"><a href="Sections.aspx">Sections</a></li>
            <li id="app_link"><a href="App.aspx">Appointment</a></li>
            <li id="reg_link"><a href="Registeration.aspx">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can use the Master property of your content page to get the master page, then use FindControl to  get the control you are looking for.

There is a how to guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

So on a the home page you'd do

1. Search master page for control 'home_link' (in your case the li item)
2. Add CssClass you want to make it appear active, to the item you have found
3. Relax

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.

        HtmlGenericControl HomeLink = null;
        HomeLink = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("HomeLinks");
        HomeLink.Style.Add["Background-color"] = blue;

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector is not precise.

The write selectors in the CSS should be like this:

```
.navbar
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:6px 0 6px 0;
margin:0;
}

.navbar li
{
display:inline;
float:left;
}

.navbar li a:active, .navbar li a:link, .navbar li a:visited
{
padding:0 14px 0 14px;
color:#32C5CF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar li a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:#cca628;
}
```

The above CSS should work as you want.